Compactness in $\mathbb{R^2}$ with subspace topology $\mathbb{Q^2}$
We are considering $\mathbb{R^2}$ with euclidean topology with Subspace $\mathbb{Q^2}$.
We need to check whether the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Q^2}\mid \mathbb{x^2+y^2=1}\}$ is compact with subspace topology.
What I have done so far that. By Heine Borel Theorem any closed and bounded Set is Compact. $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}\mid\mathbb{x^2+y^2=1}\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R^2}$ with usual topology.
So the complement of mentioned set i.e $\{(x,y) \in\mathbb{R^2}\mid\mathbb{x^2+y^2\neq1}\}$ is open. So we take intersection of this set with $\mathbb{Q^2}$ which will be compact in the subspace toplogy. So, the Set is compact.
Is this correct? I am not sure. If any wrong in my argument please help!
Options of actual ans key of the question says that This Set is not compact! But I could not find anything wrong in my argument

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It is not compact. Find a sequence in it which has no convergent subsequence.

Is this set compact in R^2 with the subspace topology

If $A\subseteq Y\subseteq X$ is compact in $Y$, then its compact in $X$. So its closed in $X$. Your set isn't closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Are we not allowed to work in metric space? As this topology is metrizable (by the usual metric in $\mathbb{R}^2).$

@AdamRubinson Yes we are allowed to use.
